# how to debug a custom proc macro?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am studying Rust macro, and i want to see the expand output of the macro.
I had tried by using command: `rustc +nightly -Zunpretty=expanded xxx.rs` follow the tutorial [The Book of Rust Macros - Debugging](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/syntax-extensions/debugging.html).
but i got the error when i use the custom macro in the same crate:
[can't use a procedural macro from the same crate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGdwA.png)

But when i moved the test code into other file, it still failed with another message:
[unresolved import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aNsY.png)

And then when i changed the code followed the help message, it change the error message:
[can't find crate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AJb8.png)

here are my demo:

```rust
use syn;
use quote::{quote, ToTokens, TokenStreamExt};
use proc_macro;

#[proc_macro_derive(HelloMacro)]
pub fn hello_macro_derive(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    // Construct a representation of Rust code as a syntax tree
    // that we can manipulate
    let ast = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    // Build the trait implementation
    impl_hello_macro(&ast)
}

fn impl_hello_macro(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let name = &ast.ident;
    let gen = quote! {
        impl HelloMacro for #name {
            fn hello_macro() -> String {
                String::from(stringify!(#name))
            }
        }
    };
    gen.into()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn test_macro () {
        trait HelloMacro {
            fn hello_macro() -> String {
                String::from("666")
            }
        }

        #[derive(HelloMacro)]
        struct A;

        
        assert_eq!(A::hello_macro(), "A".to_string());

    }
}
```

I had also tried using `cargo-expand`, but the output still incorrect.

```
error[E0514]: found crate `my_macro` compiled by an incompatible version of rustc
 --> my_macro\tests\test_macro.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use my_macro::{ HelloMacro };
  |     ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the following crate versions were found:
          crate `my_macro` compiled by rustc 1.66.1 (90743e729 2023-01-10): \\?\D:\vscode\rust-study\game\my_mine_sweeper\target\debug\deps\my_macro-b82452821ca4c556.dll
  = help: please recompile that crate using this compiler (rustc 1.69.0-nightly (2773383a3 2023-02-10)) (consider running `cargo clean` first)
error: cannot determine resolution for the derive macro `HelloMacro`
  --> my_macro\tests\test_macro.rs:11:14
   |
11 |     #[derive(HelloMacro)]
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0514`.
error: could not compile `my_macro` due to 2 previous errors

#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
use my_macro::HelloMacro;
extern crate test;
#[cfg(test)]
#[rustc_test_marker = "test_macro"]
pub const test_macro: test::TestDescAndFn = test::TestDescAndFn {
    desc: test::TestDesc {
        name: test::StaticTestName("test_macro"),
        ignore: false,
        ignore_message: ::core::option::Option::None,
        compile_fail: false,
        no_run: false,
        should_panic: test::ShouldPanic::No,
        test_type: test::TestType::IntegrationTest,
    },
    testfn: test::StaticTestFn(|| test::assert_test_result(test_macro())),
};
fn test_macro() {
    trait HelloMacro {
        fn hello_macro() -> String {
            String::from("666")
        }
    }
    struct A;
    match (&A::hello_macro(), &"A".to_string()) {
        (left_val, right_val) => {
            if !(*left_val == *right_val) {
                let kind = ::core::panicking::AssertKind::Eq;
                ::core::panicking::assert_failed(
                    kind,
                    &*left_val,
                    &*right_val,
                    ::core::option::Option::None,
                );
            }
        }
    };
}
#[rustc_main]
pub fn main() -> () {
    extern crate test;
    test::test_main_static(&[&test_macro])
}
```

I just want to know how to debug the procedural macro and see the expand output since it is  hard to know whether the result is correct.

Comment: [Please do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Thanks, i will keep it in mind.  @Chayim Friedman

Answer (score 2):

The invocation of a macro and the macro itself cannot be in the same crate.

That's why many projects are split into two crates:

- `<cratename>`
- `<cratename>-macros`

For example `tokio` and `tokio-macros`.

Usually, this is then organized into a `workspace` layout, with `<cratename>` and `<cratename>-macros` as subcrates. As in [`tokio`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio). (Note that tokio has many more subcrates, but only `tokio` and `tokio-macros` are important for your problem)

---

You are probably aware of all of this already and only want to know how to test the macros in your `<cratename>-macros` crate.

You cannot test macros in the same file. You can, however, use the [`tests` directory](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#the-tests-directory). It's more appropriate anyway, because your tests are integration tests. In-file tests are more meant for unit tests, as you have full access to struct internals. In the `tests` directory the visibility of your crate is more representative of how users would see your crate.

Like this:

- `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
use proc_macro;
use quote::quote;
use syn;

#[proc_macro_derive(HelloMacro)]
pub fn hello_macro_derive(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    // Construct a representation of Rust code as a syntax tree
    // that we can manipulate
    let ast = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    // Build the trait implementation
    impl_hello_macro(&ast)
}

fn impl_hello_macro(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let name = &ast.ident;
    let gen = quote! {
        impl HelloMacro for #name {
            fn hello_macro() -> String {
                String::from(stringify!(#name))
            }
        }
    };
    gen.into()
}
```

- `tests/test_macros.rs`:

```
use rust_playground::HelloMacro;

#[test]
fn test_macro() {
    trait HelloMacro {
        fn hello_macro() -> String {
            String::from("666")
        }
    }

    #[derive(HelloMacro)]
    struct A;

    assert_eq!(A::hello_macro(), "A".to_string());
}
```

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling rust_playground v0.1.0 (/home/martin/work/rust_playground)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.45s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/rust_playground-4e67636c4d9901bb)

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running tests/test_macros.rs (target/debug/deps/test_macros-1278dc310f04b8db)

running 1 test
test test_macro ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

   Doc-tests rust_playground

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

---

**More (potentially) helpful tips**:

For quick and dirty feedback you can also use `cargo-expand` to show what your macro expands to.

To install it, run:

```
cargo install cargo-expand
rustup component add rustfmt
```

Then, let's for example expand the `tests/test_macros.rs` file:

```
$ cargo expand --test test_macros
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
use rust_playground::HelloMacro;
extern crate test;
#[cfg(test)]
#[rustc_test_marker = "test_macro"]
pub const test_macro: test::TestDescAndFn = test::TestDescAndFn {
    desc: test::TestDesc {
        name: test::StaticTestName("test_macro"),
        ignore: false,
        ignore_message: ::core::option::Option::None,
        compile_fail: false,
        no_run: false,
        should_panic: test::ShouldPanic::No,
        test_type: test::TestType::IntegrationTest,
    },
    testfn: test::StaticTestFn(|| test::assert_test_result(test_macro())),
};
fn test_macro() {
    trait HelloMacro {
        fn hello_macro() -> String {
            String::from("666")
        }
    }
    struct A;
    impl HelloMacro for A {
        fn hello_macro() -> String {
            String::from("A")
        }
    }
    match (&A::hello_macro(), &"A".to_string()) {
        (left_val, right_val) => {
            if !(*left_val == *right_val) {
                let kind = ::core::panicking::AssertKind::Eq;
                ::core::panicking::assert_failed(
                    kind,
                    &*left_val,
                    &*right_val,
                    ::core::option::Option::None,
                );
            }
        }
    };
}
#[rustc_main]
pub fn main() -> () {
    extern crate test;
    test::test_main_static(&[&test_macro])
}
```

It is a little bit noisy because it expands **all** macros, including `#[test]`. But you can find the expansion of your macro in there:

```rust
    struct A;
    impl HelloMacro for A {
        fn hello_macro() -> String {
            String::from("A")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But i had tried this way before, the `cargo-expand` is seem like a wrapper of the command i methioned before. I don't know why your output is correct, mine isn't have the implement of the trait HelloMacro. @Finomnis

Answer (score 0):

You can fully debug proc macros by creating yet another project that your macro project refers to. It will be a normal (non-macro) project that your macro will refer to. It must use the proc_macro2 crate in place of the proc_macro crate. You can use Rust workspaces to organize all these projects.

I think it's worth adding this extra layer because it makes creating and testing macro code as easy as normal code.

For details and examples see rule #1 in [Nine Rules for Creating Procedural Macros in Rust](https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-for-creating-procedural-macros-in-rust-595aa476a7ff).

Comment: You reminded me! I can simply use `dbg!` to print out the expanded code...

Answer (score 0):

As @Carl pointed out,

> You can fully debug proc macros by creating yet another project that your macro project refers to. It will be a normal (non-macro) project that your macro will refer to. It must use the proc_macro2 crate in place of the proc_macro crate. You can use Rust workspaces to organize all these projects.

And I agree that it's worth adding this extra layer because it makes creating and testing macro code as easy as normal code.

For convenience, I've created [`proc_macro_template`](https://github.com/JohnScience/proc_macro_template) to simplify the task. It is based on "Nine Rules for Creating Procedural Macros in Rust".